# How do I make a bash script interactive midway?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
testfunc()
{
    # test function
}
testvar="test"

# some setup
bash # I get a shell here but with no access to testfunc and testvar
# some cleanup
```

This script stops and opens a shell, and I can `exit` to continue execution. However the environment is not preserved, so I can't call the functions, variables etc. set by the script and vice versa. How do I get a shell in a way that does?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want. Perhaps you will want the user to `source` your code to make the function and the variable available to the caller's shell?

Comment: @tripleee No, because I want a shell after some setup, and when the shell exits I want to do some cleanup.

Comment: You can set an `EXIT  ` trap which will fire when the child process exits. Then your original approach should be workable, at least roughly speaking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve the change in a variable that made in child process for parent process in a bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258965/how-to-preserve-the-change-in-a-variable-that-made-in-child-process-for-parent-p)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `export`

```
#!/bin/bash
testfunc()
{
    # test function
}
testvar="test"

# some setup
export -f testfunc
export testvar
bash
# some cleanup
```

Comment: @downvoters of course this answer does not cover the "vice versa" (not possible as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258965))