# Is there a way to assign sourced variables with new values?

Tags: bash

I am trying to update the values of variables that I have sourced from a .conf file in a bash script.

```
. /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf

yes=YES
no=NO

if [ $1 == "-B" ]; then
  BREAKFAST=$yes
  LUNCH=$no
  DINNER=$no
  NIGHT=$no

elif [ $1 == "-L" ]; then
  BREAKFAST=$no
  LUNCH=$yes
  DINNER=$no
  NIGHT=$no

elif [ $1 == "-D" ]; then
  BREAKFAST=$no
  LUNCH=$no
  DINNER=$yes
  NIGHT=$no

elif [ $1 == "-N" ]; then
  BREAKFAST=$no
  LUNCH=$no
  DINNER=$no
  NIGHT=$yes

fi
```

The variables BREAKFAST, LUNCH, DINNNER, and NIGHT are all initiallized to NO in a .conf file

```
BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=NO
```

The script shown above is meant to overwrite these values depending on the argument passed with it.

Additional information: There exists a start.sh script that calls a python file with the values of the 4 variables passed to it. The python file calls the script above using subprocess.check_call()

When I run this script to test it, I see nothing change. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you run the script? Did you put the option such as `-B`, `-L` or whatever?

Comment: yes, it is reading the arguments correctly but just cant assign new values for some reason... subprocess.check_call("./home/pi/OffTheDome/save_config.sh -B", shell=True) is how the python file is calling the script. I have also tried manually calling it but no difference

Comment: Thank you for the detailed feedback. What happens if you put `echo "$BREAKFAST"` at the end of `save_config.sh`? In my environment the python code above outputs `YES`.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the variables change? If you're running the script as a subprocess, it has no way to affect its parent process, so it can't change variables in the process that ran the script. See ["How to preserve the change in a variable that made in child process for parent process in a bash shell?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258965/how-to-preserve-the-change-in-a-variable-that-made-in-child-process-for-parent-p) for example.

Comment: mine does as well. However I would like the value of YES to be seen in my .conf file (located in /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf). It seems that the change in value of BREAKFAST is only in save_config.sh still

Comment: If `save_config.sh` writes to a file as the name suggests and you are examining the
file whether it is overwritten, it will be a help if you can provide the file writing portion of the code as well so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would like to see the values of these variables changing in the timeline.conf file. I have a start_timeline.sh that calls my python file, which then calls the save_config.sh to write the current state of the program (i.e which variables are set to YES/NO). I would like this so that the state of the program persists through reboots

Comment: save_config.sh is shown completely. 

The start_timeline.sh is here:
1

```. /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf

python timeline.py $BREAKFAST $LUNCH $DINNER $NIGHT```

Comment: Just modifying the shell variables does not overwrite the existing file unless you explicitly write to the file using the updated variables.

Comment: This is what I am unsure about how to do. I am still fairly new to writing scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the script, rewrite the `timeline.conf` file using the updated variables.

```
cat <<EOF >/home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
BREAKFAST=$BREAKFAST
LUNCH=$LUNCH
DINNER=$DINNER
NIGHT=$NIGHT
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample usage:

```
$ ./start.sh
======== cat /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf ========
BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=NO
=====================================================================
Usage:
To change BREAKFAST to YES
./start.sh -B
To change DINNER to YES
./start.sh -D
To change NIGHT to YES
./start.sh -N
To change LUNCH to YES
./start.sh -L
$ ./start.sh invalid parameter
======== cat /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf ========
BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=NO
=====================================================================
Usage:
To change BREAKFAST to YES
./start.sh -B
To change DINNER to YES
./start.sh -D
To change NIGHT to YES
./start.sh -N
To change LUNCH to YES
./start.sh -L
$ ./start.sh -B
$ cat /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
BREAKFAST=YES
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=NO
$ ./start.sh -L
$ cat "/home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf"
BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=YES
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=NO
$ ./start.sh -D
$ cat "/home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf"
BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=YES
NIGHT=NO
$ ./start.sh -N
$ cat /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=YES
```

Related coding:

```
$ cat ./start.sh
#!/bin/bash
#Your wish to use bash/bash.exe/mksh.exe/mksh/ksh/... based on your OS/shell.
python ./start.py $@
$ cat start.py
import os
import sys
if ( 1 == len( sys.argv ) ):
    os.system( "./73535990.sh")
else:
    os.system( "./73535990.sh "+sys.argv[1])
$ cat 73535990.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -f /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf ]]
then
        echo "BREAKFAST=NO
LUNCH=NO
DINNER=NO
NIGHT=NO">/home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
        if [ 0 -ne $? ]
        then
                echo "Unable to create/update file /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf"
                exit 1
        fi
fi
. /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
yes=YES
no=NO
if [[ 0 -eq $# || "-B" != "$1" && "-L" != "$1" && "-D" != "$1" && "-N" != "$1" ]]
then
        echo "======== cat /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf ========"
        cat /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
        echo "====================================================================="
        echo "Usage:"
        echo "To change BREAKFAST to $yes"
        echo "./start.sh -B"
        echo "To change DINNER to $yes"
        echo "./start.sh -D"
        echo "To change NIGHT to $yes"
        echo "./start.sh -N"
        echo "To change LUNCH to $yes"
        echo "./start.sh -L"
        exit 1
elif [ "$1" == "-B" ]
then
        sed -i "s/BREAKFAST=NO/BREAKFAST=YES/;s/LUNCH=YES/LUNCH=NO/;s/DINNER=YES/DINNER=NO/;s/NIGHT=YES/NIGHT=NO/;" /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
elif [ "$1" == "-L" ]
then
        sed -i "s/BREAKFAST=YES/BREAKFAST=NO/;s/LUNCH=NO/LUNCH=YES/;s/DINNER=YES/DINNER=NO/;s/NIGHT=YES/NIGHT=NO/;" /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
elif [ "$1" == "-D" ]
then
        sed -i "s/BREAKFAST=YES/BREAKFAST=NO/;s/LUNCH=YES/LUNCH=NO/;s/DINNER=NO/DINNER=YES/;s/NIGHT=YES/NIGHT=NO/;" /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
elif [ "$1" == "-N" ]
then
        sed -i "s/BREAKFAST=YES/BREAKFAST=NO/;s/LUNCH=YES/LUNCH=NO/;s/DINNER=YES/DINNER=NO/;s/NIGHT=NO/NIGHT=YES/;" /home/pi/OffTheDome/config/timeline.conf
fi
```